# Receive many file with server

Tags: vb.net

I use a program to receive file that client send with specific port.
The problem is when a lot of client send file to this server, it wait to receive file in order, it receive files consecutive.
Now i need help to change this code that it received files Parallel.
For example 10 client, send file to this server.it receive all file in order, but i need it receive them Parallel.
I hope you understand what i want.

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.IO

Module Module1
Public destinationfolder As String
Dim rcf As New RecievedFile
Public port As String

Sub Main()
    Console.Title = "B64S Server"
    Console.WindowHeight = 30
    DrawGraphics(2)
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray
    Console.WriteLine("   Created by: Turbocharged Chameleon")
    DrawGraphics(2) ''draws some graphics from another sub
    DrawGraphics(0)
    DrawGraphics(2)
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White
    Console.WriteLine("Destination Folder:")
    destinationfolder = Console.ReadLine() ''reads line for destination folder
    Console.WriteLine("Port:")
    port = Console.ReadLine() ''reads line and sets the port
    If Directory.Exists(destinationfolder) = False Then
        MsgBox("destination folder doesn't exist!")
        End ''ends program if folder doesn't exist
    End If
    Console.Clear()
    ''wait
    DrawGraphics(1)
    rcf.Threader = New Thread(New System.Threading.ThreadStart(AddressOf rcf.enter code hereRecieve))
    rcf.Threader.Start() ''starts listening on port for incoming data
End Sub
Private Sub DrawGraphics(ByVal int As Integer)
     If int = 0 Then
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray
        Console.WriteLine("MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM")
        Console.WriteLine("MMMMMMMMMMMMMM$,.........$MMMMOMMMMMMMMM")
        Console.WriteLine("MMMMMMMMMMM8,,......... ..  M....MMMMMMM")
 ElseIf int = 1 Then
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray
        Console.WriteLine("MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMII+++:::::==+++??$$$MMMMM")
        Console.WriteLine("MMMMMMMMMMII???~~.............~~$$$MMMMM")
        Console.WriteLine("MMMMMMMMMMII???~~.............~~$$$MMMMM")
 ElseIf int = 2 Then
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------")
    End If
End Sub
End Module
```

and Recieved File Class:

```
Public Class RecievedFile
Public Threader As Thread
Dim TCPListener As TcpListener
Dim Socket As Socket

Sub Recieve()
    Try
        TCPListener = New TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port)
        TCPListener.Start()
        While True
            Try
                Socket = TCPListener.AcceptSocket
                Dim MyNetworkStream As NetworkStream = New NetworkStream(Socket)
                Dim mystreamreader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(MyNetworkStream)
                Console.WriteLine("Recieving file...")
                Dim str As String = mystreamreader.ReadToEnd
                Console.WriteLine(str)
                Dim fn As String = str.Remove(str.IndexOf("#"))
                Dim filenamelength As Integer = fn.Length
                Dim b64string As String = str.Substring(str.IndexOf("#") + 1)
                Console.WriteLine("BS64")
                Dim binaryData() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(b64string)
                Console.WriteLine("done")
                If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(destinationfolder & "\" & fn) Then
                    System.IO.File.Delete(destinationfolder & "\" & fn)



                    Dim fs As New FileStream(destinationfolder & "\" & fn, FileMode.CreateNew)
                    fs.Write(binaryData, 0, binaryData.Length)
                    fs.Close()
                    Console.WriteLine("Recieved file: " & fn)
                Else
                    Dim fs As New FileStream(destinationfolder & "\" & fn, FileMode.CreateNew)
                    fs.Write(binaryData, 0, binaryData.Length)
                    fs.Close()
                    Console.WriteLine("Recieved file: " & fn)
                End If

            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End While
    Catch ex2 As Exception
        MsgBox(ex2.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Definitively TCP.  You are using Sync method which is blocking and will only allow one transfer at a time.  You must use Async method to allow transfers in parallel.  Write a new class with the fs.Write() methods using Async method.  One for each client connection.

Comment: Very good, i search about async method and understood how it works. but i did not find out how to use it here. would you please explain or help me with this code?

Comment: A Sync method is one that doesn't return until it is completed.  This stops other threads from running so you can't perform parallel code.  So in your case mystreamreader.ReadToEnd and fs.Write() are a Sync method.  An ASync method is one that uses events so it can be interrupted and allow other threads to run.

Comment: I search again and did not find out where should i use `System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf *)` and what should i insert instead of `*` in this code.would you please overwrite my code?im afraid to understand this method clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe pass the receiver part of the code into a new instance of a background worker?

That might allow each stream to come in on its own thread.

I haven't tried, but that was just the first thought that came to mind.